# How to use text2wav.node.js ? Sound is pretty unclear

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech

I am using this module. My code is very simple to save it to project directory. But sounds are not clear even I am not being able to understand it. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
async function Final() { 
  let out1 = await text2wav("Good Morning, friends, how are you? 
   Will you go there or not ? Let me know . ", { speed: 160 });
  fs.writeFileSync("test1.wav", Buffer.from(out1.buffer)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text2wave uses [espeak-ng](https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng) under the hood and uses Klatt formant synthesis. You can try changing the voice - some may be more pleasing to your ear than others, but it's always going to give you the classical "computer voice" sound. If you want something more realistic than you can use the OS synthesis engine (Windows/OSX) or an online service like Google Wavenet or AWS Polly.